# Django Returns Not Found on Production Server

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my code on `digitalocean` `vps` server and I checked everything million times but I still have the same problem.

When I try to access admin page it works but I cannot access any other page. I am not running django code local it's running on a public ip.

Can anyone help me with it ?

Here is my main **urls.py** file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'), name='rest_framework'),
    path('posts/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('dictionary/', include('dictionary.urls')),
]
```

Here is my **post/urls.py** file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "posts"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list,name = "list"),
    path('create/', views.post_create,name="create"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail,name="detail"),
    path('<slug:slug>/edit/', views.post_update,name="update"),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/', views.post_delete,name="delete"),
    ]
```

Comment: Does it work during development (meaning, with `DEBUG=True`) ? Does it work when you run in in your local machine?

Comment: It works on my computer but when I run it even with DEBUG = True on vps it still does the same thing.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you seeing an error page like 404, 500 or something else?

Comment: On the page it just returns :Not Found The requested URL /posts/  was not found on this server.

Comment: Can you show us your `urls.py` for the `posts` app? Please add it to your question.

Comment: It is just the `posts` or any other url that gives the 404?

Comment: All the urls including api-auth returns not found. Only the url for admin page is working.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to your code, if it works on your local machine. 1) Are you sure your code is deployed correctly (can you check logging into admin that the `Post` and `Dictionary` models are there, or ssh into the vps and check that the source code is up to date?). 2) What's your server's configuration, how are requests routed to your application server?

Comment: Yes everything works fine in admin. I can create and delete stuff. I just followed digital ocean's deployment guide so I just have the basic server configurations shown in the guide.

Comment: It's a long shot but people sometimes forget that they have to upload their main url file too. url file in your main directory next to settings.py